# Chef - How Reboot VM and continue performing actions

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

In a Chef recipe, I need to perform a reboot on a Node after doing some actions,
and after the reboot is done, I need to continue doing another actions:

Recipe:
  -action 1
  -action 2
  -reboot
  -action3
  -action4....

I have checked some existing cookbook in the community: reboot-handler, chef-reboot, chef-restart, chef-dominous, but I cannot make any of them work.

Is there some method in Chef to get what I need?
Please provide detailed examples.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, it is Linux: Centos 6.5 and Redhat 6.x

Comment: The concept similar I found is the proposed by chef-restart cookbook which also has a nice way to restart the login shell: https://github.com/keenlabs/chef-restart
But it throws many errors, seems it hasn't been updated since a while and now is incompatible with recent versions of Chef or some other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [chef tags](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/dsl_recipe.html#tag-tagged-and-untag) to implement a series of state transitions? This approach can be combined this with [reboot-handler](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/reboot-handler) cookbook to manage the actual reboots.

## Example

### default.rb

```
#
# Action recipes
#
include_recipe "mycookbook::action1"
include_recipe "mycookbook::action2"

#
# State transitions
#
if tagged?("doAction1")

  untag("doAction1")
  tag("doAction2")

elsif tagged?("doAction2")

  untag("doAction2")

end
```

### action1.rb

```
if tagged?("doAction1")

  ..
  ..

end
```

### action2.rb

```
include_recipe "reboot-handler"

if tagged?("doAction2")

  ..
  ..

  # Trigger reboot at end of chef run
  node.run_state['reboot'] = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I see of the example is that the reboot is run at the end of the Chef run, but what I need is to add another action after the reboot, I mean I need to have a reboot in the middle of execution and the Chef doesnt "cut the run" and keep runnig after the reboot the next action. The problem of reboot-handler is that it schedule a reboot at the end.
The most similar concept I found is the chef-restart cookbook:
https://github.com/keenlabs/chef-restart
but seems it is old and not working with newer Chef versions and not support Centos/Redhat SO.

Comment: @user2620348 That is the purpose of using tags. The "doAction1" tag enables functionality to be applied before the reboot and the "doAction2" tag enables functionality to be applied after the reboot.

Comment: Where is the "doAction1" tag first applied? I can see where doAction2 gets applied in your example, but I can't see where doAction2 is set.

Comment: @StefanoRicciardi You've pointed out that something needs to trigger the workflow. The questioner didn't specify the criteria. The simplest way to set a tag (and thereby trigger something) is to use the "knife tag" command. https://docs.chef.io/knife_tag.html

Answer (score 1):

```
This is a recipe of mine you can try.
# Cookbook Name:: reboot-test
# Recipe:: default

bash 'reboot' do
     cwd '/tmp'
      code <<-EOH
      touch reboot.lock
      chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
#     echo "/usr/local/bin/chef-client" >> /etc/rc.d/rc.local
      cp /etc/rc.d/rc.local /etc/rc.d/rc.local_bkp
      echo "/bin/chef-client" >> /etc/rc.d/rc.local
      reboot
      EOH
      ignore_failure true
      not_if do ::File.exists?('/tmp/reboot.lock') end
      not_if 'ls -lrth /tmp/reboot.lock'
     end

#This is where you need to code for the config automation like the execute #resource but before the bash resource "CHEF-CLIENT-#EXIT"

execute 'touch' do
     command '/bin/touch /tmp/suman.test'
     end

bash 'chef_client_exit' do
      code <<-EOH
      rm -rf /tmp/reboot.lock
#     sed -i '/\/usr\/local\/bin\/chef-client/d' /etc/rc.d/rc.local
#     sed -e '/^\/bin\/chef-client/d' -i /etc/rc.d/rc.local
#     sed -e '\|^/bin/chef-client|d' -i /etc/rc.d/rc.local
      cp /etc/rc.d/rc.local_bkp /etc/rc.d/rc.local
      rm -rf /etc/rc.d/rc.local_bkp
      EOH
      only_if 'grep -i chef-client /etc/rc.d/rc.local'
     end
```

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using FLAG file method, example given below.
Example of domain join-

> Blockquote

```
---------------------------Script Start------------------------

    powershell_script 'Domain_Join' do
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    code -domainJoin
    $currentTime = Get-Date
    $currentTimeString = $currentTime.ToString()

  $systemDomain = (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain
  If (($systemDomain) -eq 'domainName')
  { 
    Try {
  write-host "$env:computerName is DOMAIN MEMBER"
  Remove-Item C:\\DomainJoinFlag.txt -ErrorAction Stop
  Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Chef client schedule_DJ" -Confirm:$false
  } # end of Try
          Catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]
            { write-host "Server is already domain member, Or Exception raised due to either missing FLAG file or Server startup schedule task configuration." 
              eventcreate /t INFORMATION /ID 0909 /L APPLICATION /SO "ChefClient_$env:computerName" /D "Server is already domain member, Or Exception raised due to either missing FLAG file or Server startup schedule task configuration. Refer to the CHEF reciepie for DomainJoin or check Administrative credentials for creting schedule task"}
            }
    else { write-host "$env:computerName is NOT domain member, joining the server to the domain. Server will be rebooting in a while..."
            eventcreate /t INFORMATION /ID 0909 /L APPLICATION /SO "ChefClient_$env:computerName" /D "Joining the server : $env:ComputerName to the domain ININLAB.COM (Server Time): $currentTimeString"
            New-Item C:\\DomainJoinFlag.txt -type file -force
            write-host "$env:computerName DOMAIN JOIN INITIATED for the server"
            $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\\domain_user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force))
            Add-Computer -DomainName "domainName" -Credential $cred -OUPath "OU=HyperV,OU=Infrastructure,OU=Servers,DC=domain,DC=name"
            shutdown -r -t 120
            } #end_of_else
            domainJoin
  notifies :run, 'windows_task[Chef client schedule_DJ]', :immediately
end

windows_task 'Chef client schedule_DJ' do
  user 'SYSTEM'
  command 'chef-client -L C:\chef\chef-client_after_reboot_domainJoin.log'
  run_level :highest
  frequency :onstart
  frequency_modifier 30
  action :create
  only_if { ::File.exist?('C:\\DomainJoinFlag.txt') }
end

---------------------------Script Ends------------------------
```

Comment: Please explain your answer