# Chef chef-restart cookbook updates (to reboot node and refresh user profile changes)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Anyone knows how can I encourage Chef team to update the cookbook chef-restart ?
https://github.com/keenlabs/chef-restart
It is old and is not working with last Chef versions, also it doesn't support Centos/RedHat/Fedora.

Chef doesn't have a way to perform a reboot of a Node in the middle of the execution without cutting the execution and then keep executing other actions after the point of the reboot,
and this feature is very important since some package installation needs to reboot the system to work ok.

I see chef-restart cookbook is aimed to perform that also to refresh user profiles when profile.d, bashrc, etc are modified and need to be refreshed to take effect.

Thanks a lot.

**PS:** chef-reboot, reboot-hanlder doesn't meet this requirement because they schedule a reboot at the end of the chef execution and not in the middle keeping running the next actions after the reboot.

Comment: This is not a question and has no actionable items.

Comment: Also this cookbook isn't developed by Chef Software (nee Opscode) so there is no "Chef team" involved in this. You can find Keen's contact information on their website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef - How Reboot VM and continue performing actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497840/chef-how-reboot-vm-and-continue-performing-actions)