# Reboot/restart node in between chef run

Tags: windows, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, vagrant-windows

Chef experts,
Its really important and critical to my project so posting to get some real fast guidance.
Requirement: Need to reboot VM in between chef run.
Example: Recipe1->Recipe2(Install windows feature which require reboot)->reboot machine->recipe3->recipe4
Tried methods: used windows::reboot_handler, but it reboots the node only at the end of chef run.

[Reference][1]
**strong text**  [1]: [Chef - How Reboot VM and continue performing actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497840/chef-how-reboot-vm-and-continue-performing-actions)

**More details**:

Well my issue in detail:
I am trying to automate BIT-LOCKER in windows file servers, where i first need to add windows service "bitlocker" to enable the power shell commands for bit-locker automation, which needs a reboot.
So i want to do bit-locker automation after reboot happen in a single chef run.
More precisely i want below execution cycle :
**Recipe1 (install bit-locker windows service)** -> **Want to reboot node here** -> **Recipe2 (bit-locker auotmation code here)** 
**Code:**
Recipe1 :
 windows_feature 'BitLocker' do
       action :install
 end
I want to add reboot logic after this as this installation needs a reboot to enable powershell command for bit-locker.

Please help

Comment: Please take your time to explain at what point you are struggling and what code you are using.

Comment: If it's critical and you need fast response, buy a professional support from [chef.io](https://www.chef.io/service-level-agreement/#support) or another service company. SO is not a free code service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef - How Reboot VM and continue performing actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497840/chef-how-reboot-vm-and-continue-performing-actions)